# Do I have to manually clone after each push?

Tags: git

I have a github project which I edit locally (lets call it place A) and then commit/push changes.

I have now cloned this github project to a different computer (place B).

If I make a change in place B and commit/push to github then when I open my local at Place A, then Place A will not be up-to-date with the github.

My question is when I move between Place A and Place B do I need to manually clone the github project every-time to ensure everything is always synced.

I'm new at git so I am just making sure I am doing this the right way.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just do a pull operation instead.

This will get only the new changes, so no need to do clone.

Clone can be done for just the first time. After that, it's just commit, push, pull.

Comment: Thank you. What is the correct command line instruction to pull if I push using 'push origin master'

Answer (score 0):

just use: "git pull" and then "git up"
"git clone http//..." is only used the first time you want to get the source files